# Can we use spark on Kubernetes in PROD env with beta edition?

Tags: apache-spark

we are planning to deploy all spark batch and streaming jobs on Kubernetes (as cluster services). I want to know if we can deploy all spark jobs using spark operator manifest file in PROD Kubernetes Server.

Kubernetes cluster

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/jobs/dataproc-gke wherein you can run a Dataproc cluster on GKE. It is a managed service by Google Cloud.